# goBack() function inside canvas doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a goBack() function in JavaScript, which basically is an undo button. For example: The user drags and drops 1 image and draws 2 lines. The goBack() function should remove the lines one at the time, and then removes the image. My function removes the lines and the images, but not in order. It removes first the image, even if it was the first thing dragged. Here is the code for better understanding.

```js
//Javascript per la creazione di cirucuiti elettrici

const NUMERO_CICLO = 990;
const NUMERO_CICLO_INTERNO = 60;

const resistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_resistor');
const condensator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_condensator');
const tranistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_tranistor');
const alimentator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_alimentator');
const circuit = document.getElementById('components_circuit');
const back_button = document.getElementById('back-button');
const clear_button = document.getElementById('clear-button');
const draggable = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const foward_button = document.getElementById('foward-button');

/** EDIT START */
const draggableImages = document.querySelectorAll('img[draggable]');

for (let i = 0; i < draggableImages.length; i++)
  draggableImages[i].ondragstart = (ev) => {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', i.toString());
  };

canvas.ondragover = (ev) => ev.preventDefault(); // IMPORTANT

const drawnImageData = [];
const deletedImageData = [];

canvas.ondrop = (ev) => {
  const index = parseInt(ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
  const img = draggableImages[index];
  drawnImageData.push({ img, x: ev.offsetX, y: ev.offsetY });
};
clear_button.disabled = true;
clear_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
foward_button.disabled = true;
foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
back_button.disabled = true;
back_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
/** EDIT END */

canvas.width = 1500;
canvas.height = 855;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
circuit.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.style.borderRadius = '10px';
canvas.style.marginLeft = 'auto';
canvas.style.marginRight = 'auto';
canvas.style.display = 'block';
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const circles = [];
const lines = [];
const lines_c = [];
var deletedLines = [];

for (let y = 20; y <= NUMERO_CICLO; y += 20) {
  for (let i = 0; i < NUMERO_CICLO_INTERNO; i++) {
    circles.push({
      x: 13 + i * 25,
      y,
      radius: 5,
      color: 'grey',
    });
  }
}

let startCircle = null;
let endCircle = null;
var priorita = null;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = circle.color;
    ctx.fill();
  });
  lines.forEach((line) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.moveTo(line.start.x, line.start.y);
    ctx.lineTo(line.end.x, line.end.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  });
  if (startCircle && endCircle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.moveTo(startCircle.x, startCircle.y);
    ctx.lineTo(endCircle.x, endCircle.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  /** EDIT START */
  for (const data of drawnImageData)
    ctx.drawImage(data.img, data.x, data.y, data.img.width, data.img.height);

  /** EDIT END */
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  if(drawnImageData.length > 0 || lines.length > 0){
    clear_button.disabled = false;
    clear_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    back_button.disabled = false;
    back_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  }
}
draw();

function goBack() {
  if (drawnImageData.length > 0) {
    deletedImageData.push(drawnImageData.pop());
  }
  else if (lines.length > 0) {
    deletedLines.push(lines.pop());
  }
  // Check if there are any items left to undo
  if (drawnImageData.length === 0 && lines.length === 0) {
    back_button.disabled = true;
    back_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
    clear_button.disabled = true;
    clear_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
  }
  // Enable the forward button
  foward_button.disabled = false;
  foward_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}

function goFoward() {
  if (deletedImageData.length > 0) {
    drawnImageData.push(deletedImageData.pop());
  } else if (deletedLines.length > 0) {
    lines.push(deletedLines.pop());
  }
  // Check if there are any items left to redo
  if (deletedImageData.length === 0 && deletedLines.length === 0) {
    foward_button.disabled = true;
    foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
  }

  // Enable the back button
  back_button.disabled = false;
  back_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}

function clearCanvas() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the circuit?')) {
    lines.length = 0;
    deletedLines.length = 0;
    lastDeleted = null;

    // clear drawn images data
    drawnImageData.length = 0;

    clear_button.disabled = true;
    clear_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
    foward_button.disabled = true;
    foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
    back_button.disabled = true;
    back_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
  }
}

function getNearestCircle(x, y) {
  let nearestCircle = null;
  let nearestDistance = Infinity;
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    const distance = Math.sqrt((circle.x - x) ** 2 + (circle.y - y) ** 2);
    if (distance < nearestDistance && distance < 30) {
      nearestCircle = circle;
      nearestDistance = distance;
    }
  });
  return nearestCircle;
}

let isDrawing = false;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  const x = event.offsetX;
  const y = event.offsetY;
  const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
  if (circle) {
    startCircle = circle;
    endCircle = { x, y };
    isDrawing = true;
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (isDrawing) {
    endCircle.x = event.offsetX;
    endCircle.y = event.offsetY;
  } else {
    const x = event.offsetX;
    const y = event.offsetY;
    const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
    if (circle) {
      circles.forEach((circle) => {
        circle.color = 'grey';
      });
      circle.color = 'red';
    } else {
      circles.forEach((circle) => {
        circle.color = 'grey';
      });
    }
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  if (isDrawing) {
    const x = endCircle.x;
    const y = endCircle.y;
    const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
    if (circle) {
      lines.push({
        start: startCircle,
        end: circle,
      });
    }
    isDrawing = false;
    startCircle = null;
    endCircle = null;
  }
});

//back_button.addEventListener("click", goBack);
//foward_button.addEventListener("click", goBack);
clear_button.addEventListener('click', clearCanvas);

var back_clicked = false;
back_button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  back_clicked = true;
  goBack();
  back_clicked = false;
});

var foward_clicked = false;
foward_button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  foward_clicked = true;
  goFoward();
  foward_clicked = false;
});
```

```html
<h1 id="h1_titolo">From Circuit to Breadboard</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="components">
    <div id="components_circuit">
      <h3 id="h3_componenti_circuit">Componenti:</h3>
      <ul id="components_circuit_border">
        <li>
          <img
            id="component_circuit_resistor"
            src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/006/428/637738.jpg"
            height="50"
            draggable
          />
        </li>
        <br /><br />
        <li>
          <img
            id="component_circuit_condensator"
            src="https://ftw.usatoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/90/2017/05/spongebob.jpg"
            height="50"
            draggable
          />
        </li>
        <br /><br />
        <li>
          <img
            id="component_circuit_transistor"
            src="https://pyxis.nymag.com/v1/imgs/0f9/f96/029acbf4c6d8c67e138e1eb06a277204bf-05-patrick.rsquare.w700.jpg"
            height="50"
            draggable
          />
        </li>
        <br /><br />
      </ul>
      <div class="elementi_disegno">
        <h1 id="h1_disegna">Disegna il tuo circuito!</h1>
        <button id="back-button">
          Indietro
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">undo</span>
        </button>
        <button id="foward-button">
          Avanti
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">redo</span>
        </button>
        <button id="clear-button">
          Clear All
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
        </button>
        <canvas id="canvas" class="dropzone"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't save the order of the execution. In your `goBack()` function, you always try to delete from `drawnImageData` array first if the array is not empty, even if the latest execution was drawing lines. I would preserve the order of execution by making another array like:

```
const orderStack = [];
const deletedOrderStack = [];
```

Here's your updated snippet:

```js
//Javascript per la creazione di cirucuiti elettrici

const NUMERO_CICLO = 990;
const NUMERO_CICLO_INTERNO = 60;

const resistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_resistor');
const condensator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_condensator');
const tranistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_tranistor');
const alimentator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_alimentator');
const circuit = document.getElementById('components_circuit');
const back_button = document.getElementById('back-button');
const clear_button = document.getElementById('clear-button');
const draggable = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const foward_button = document.getElementById('foward-button');

/** EDIT START */
const draggableImages = document.querySelectorAll('img[draggable]');

for (let i = 0; i < draggableImages.length; i++)
  draggableImages[i].ondragstart = (ev) => {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', i.toString());
  };

canvas.ondragover = (ev) => ev.preventDefault(); // IMPORTANT

const orderStack = [];
const deletedOrderStack = [];

const drawnImageData = [];
const deletedImageData = [];

canvas.ondrop = (ev) => {
  const index = parseInt(ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
  const img = draggableImages[index];
  drawnImageData.push({
    img,
    x: ev.offsetX,
    y: ev.offsetY
  });
  orderStack.push(1);
};
clear_button.disabled = true;
clear_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
foward_button.disabled = true;
foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
back_button.disabled = true;
back_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
/** EDIT END */

canvas.width = 1500;
canvas.height = 855;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
circuit.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.style.borderRadius = '10px';
canvas.style.marginLeft = 'auto';
canvas.style.marginRight = 'auto';
canvas.style.display = 'block';
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const circles = [];
const lines = [];
const lines_c = [];
var deletedLines = [];

for (let y = 20; y <= NUMERO_CICLO; y += 20) {
  for (let i = 0; i < NUMERO_CICLO_INTERNO; i++) {
    circles.push({
      x: 13 + i * 25,
      y,
      radius: 5,
      color: 'grey',
    });
  }
}

let startCircle = null;
let endCircle = null;
var priorita = null;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = circle.color;
    ctx.fill();
  });
  lines.forEach((line) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.moveTo(line.start.x, line.start.y);
    ctx.lineTo(line.end.x, line.end.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  });
  if (startCircle && endCircle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.moveTo(startCircle.x, startCircle.y);
    ctx.lineTo(endCircle.x, endCircle.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  /** EDIT START */
  for (const data of drawnImageData)
    ctx.drawImage(data.img, data.x, data.y, data.img.width, data.img.height);

  /** EDIT END */
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  if (drawnImageData.length > 0 || lines.length > 0) {
    clear_button.disabled = false;
    clear_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    back_button.disabled = false;
    back_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  }
}
draw();

function goBack() {
  if (orderStack.length === 0) {
    return
  }

  if (orderStack[orderStack.length - 1] === 1 && drawnImageData.length > 0) {
    deletedImageData.push(drawnImageData.pop());
  } else if (orderStack[orderStack.length - 1] === 0 && lines.length > 0) {
    deletedLines.push(lines.pop());
  }

  deletedOrderStack.push(orderStack.pop())

  // Check if there are any items left to undo
  if (drawnImageData.length === 0 && lines.length === 0) {
    back_button.disabled = true;
    back_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
    clear_button.disabled = true;
    clear_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
  }
  // Enable the forward button
  foward_button.disabled = false;
  foward_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}

function goFoward() {
  if (deletedOrderStack.length === 0) {
    return
  }

  if (deletedOrderStack[deletedOrderStack.length - 1] === 1 && deletedImageData.length > 0) {
    drawnImageData.push(deletedImageData.pop());
    orderStack.push(deletedOrderStack.pop());
  } else if (deletedOrderStack[deletedOrderStack.length - 1] === 0 && deletedLines.length > 0) {
    lines.push(deletedLines.pop());
    orderStack.push(deletedOrderStack.pop());
  }
  // Check if there are any items left to redo
  if (deletedImageData.length === 0 && deletedLines.length === 0) {
    foward_button.disabled = true;
    foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
  }

  // Enable the back button
  back_button.disabled = false;
  back_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}

function clearCanvas() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the circuit?')) {
    lines.length = 0;
    deletedLines.length = 0;
    lastDeleted = null;

    // clear drawn images data
    drawnImageData.length = 0;

    orderStack.length = 0
    deletedOrderStack.length = 0

    clear_button.disabled = true;
    clear_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
    foward_button.disabled = true;
    foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
    back_button.disabled = true;
    back_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
  }
}

function getNearestCircle(x, y) {
  let nearestCircle = null;
  let nearestDistance = Infinity;
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    const distance = Math.sqrt((circle.x - x) ** 2 + (circle.y - y) ** 2);
    if (distance < nearestDistance && distance < 30) {
      nearestCircle = circle;
      nearestDistance = distance;
    }
  });
  return nearestCircle;
}

let isDrawing = false;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  const x = event.offsetX;
  const y = event.offsetY;
  const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
  if (circle) {
    startCircle = circle;
    endCircle = {
      x,
      y
    };
    isDrawing = true;
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (isDrawing) {
    endCircle.x = event.offsetX;
    endCircle.y = event.offsetY;
  } else {
    const x = event.offsetX;
    const y = event.offsetY;
    const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
    if (circle) {
      circles.forEach((circle) => {
        circle.color = 'grey';
      });
      circle.color = 'red';
    } else {
      circles.forEach((circle) => {
        circle.color = 'grey';
      });
    }
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  if (isDrawing) {
    const x = endCircle.x;
    const y = endCircle.y;
    const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
    if (circle) {
      lines.push({
        start: startCircle,
        end: circle,
      });

      orderStack.push(0);
    }
    isDrawing = false;
    startCircle = null;
    endCircle = null;
  }
});

//back_button.addEventListener("click", goBack);
//foward_button.addEventListener("click", goBack);
clear_button.addEventListener('click', clearCanvas);

var back_clicked = false;
back_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  back_clicked = true;
  goBack();
  back_clicked = false;
});

var foward_clicked = false;
foward_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  foward_clicked = true;
  goFoward();
  foward_clicked = false;
});
```

```html
<h1 id="h1_titolo">From Circuit to Breadboard</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="components">
    <div id="components_circuit">
      <h3 id="h3_componenti_circuit">Componenti:</h3>
      <ul id="components_circuit_border">
        <li>
          <img id="component_circuit_resistor" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/006/428/637738.jpg" height="50" draggable />
        </li>
        <br /><br />
        <li>
          <img id="component_circuit_condensator" src="https://ftw.usatoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/90/2017/05/spongebob.jpg" height="50" draggable />
        </li>
        <br /><br />
        <li>
          <img id="component_circuit_transistor" src="https://pyxis.nymag.com/v1/imgs/0f9/f96/029acbf4c6d8c67e138e1eb06a277204bf-05-patrick.rsquare.w700.jpg" height="50" draggable />
        </li>
        <br /><br />
      </ul>
      <div class="elementi_disegno">
        <h1 id="h1_disegna">Disegna il tuo circuito!</h1>
        <button id="back-button">
          Indietro
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">undo</span>
        </button>
        <button id="foward-button">
          Avanti
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">redo</span>
        </button>
        <button id="clear-button">
          Clear All
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
        </button>
        <canvas id="canvas" class="dropzone"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
```